# How can I send different SMS' to multiple recipients in a loop

Tags: symbian

I'm using Symbian C++ to create my code, I'm using S60 5th Ed SDK

I want to know how to send different messages - Their body text not the same - to multiple recipients in a for-loop ?

I've tried the example below, but when I try to use it in a loop it crashes due to ActiveObjects properties, as I should wait to AO to finish before calling it again.

[Sending_SMS_in_S60_3rd_Edition_MTM](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Sending_SMS_in_S60_3rd_Edition_-_MTM)

Below is example of what I need to do:

```
SendSMSL();     // **I call this function once to start the process**

// **iRecepients is a CDesCArray contains phone numbers**
// ** iSMSBody is a CDesCArray contains each contact SMS body text**

void CSMS::SendSMSL()
  {

  if(iRecepients->Count() >= 1) 
    {
        TInt x = iRecepients->Count()-1;
        TInt y = iSMSBody->Count()-1; 

        // **If the sms validating and scheduling succeeded then delete last item from both arrays**
        if(iSMSHandler->SendL((*iRecepients)[x],(*iSMSBody)[y])
            {
                iRecepients->Delete(x);
                iSMSBody->Delete(y);    
            }
    }
 }
```

Now, in the code above I call iSMSHandler->SendL() which send sms using AO, and in **iSMSHandler** object **RunL()** function, I call back the function above **CSMS::SendSMSL()** , which in turn checks if there is still anymore iRecepients elements and then call again iSMSHandler->SendL() AO , and keeps this way till no more iRecepients.

Looking forward to hear your feedback on the modification above.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you posted doesn't work for me so I can't see the rest of the code.

Assuming that iSmsHandler is a class that uses active objects to send SMS messages,
I see several issues with your loop.

1) You need to wait for the first asynchronous SendL to complete before you can issue the next SendL
2) The buf variable can not go out of scope until the SendL completes. (This may be the reason for your crash)

I suggest that you keep the textbuffer somewhere else, like together with iSmsHandler, and then code the active object that is called when SendL completes to issue the next SendL.

All of this is guesses since I have no idea what class iSmsHandler is....

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I updated the link above. and I updated the code above based on your guide, let me know if there is something wrong.

Comment: It's not the prettiest solution I've seen, but it should work. My point 2 above does not apply as CSmsHandler copies the string into an internal buffer when you call SendL.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and if you can support me with a link with a better solution than I used above that would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I no longer work with Symbian and don't have the time to do that. There is nothing technically wrong with the solution, but it seems to connect your classes in complicated ways. If it was my project -- and I had the time to spend -- I would try to make the CSmsHandler and CSMS use a better defined interface for active objects and callbacks.